# Надо ли удалить папку с установками на Ubuntu, после того как Kubernetes заработал?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, kubernetes

Установил **Kubernetes на Ubuntu**. Не до конца понял. Сделал вот так:

- Установил **Docker**
- Установил **VirtualBox** (*может быть на Ubuntu он вообще не нужен был, не понял*).
- Далее на диске с файлами `/mnt/541d54bf-...-b8676fc83fdb/`  создал директорию `kuber` и перешёл в неё в терминале.
- Далее команда из документации
  `curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"`
  Я так понял это команда на скачивание утилиты **Kubectl**
- Установка
  `sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl`
  После этого в директории `/usr/local/bin/` появился файл `kubectl`
- Далее скачивание и установка **Minikube**:
  `curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64`
  `sudo install minikube-linux-amd64 /usr/local/bin/minikube`

В итоге:

- В папке `/mnt/541d54bf-...-b8676fc83fdb/kuber/` у меня находятся 2 файла `kubectl` и `minikube-linux-amd64`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- А в папке `/usr/local/bin/` находятся файлы `kubectl` и `minikube`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос такой:

1. Я правильно понимаю, что содержимое директории `/mnt/541d54bf-...-b8676fc83fdb/kuber/` это просто скачанные файлы? **И я могу удалить директорию `kuber` ?** Ведь вроде всё установилось в `/usr/local/bin/`
2. И ещё тут же спрошу: **а мне вообще изначально нужен был VirtualBox?** Или его надо ставить только если устанавливаешь Kubernetes на **Windows**, а на **Ubuntu** и без него работает? Просто в видео лекции по установке кубера на виндоус, там прямо видно было что при запуске кластера в VirtualBox создаётся виртуальная машина, и в неё даже зайти можно. А в моём случае на ubuntu я ничего не вижу глазами в VirtualBox.

Comment: Разве кубернетес не рулит докером? Смысл в установке вбокса?

Comment: Вам все это не надо.
Надо:
* Ознакомиться как можно ставить кубер без всего это:
- https://docs.docker.com/desktop/kubernetes - в докере он включается одной кнопкой.